# Invalid date en safari e IOS (ionic framework)

Tags: angularjs, ionic, momentjs

Tengo el siguiente Json con fechas:

```
nuevo=[
    { "rr":"4-1-2016" }, { "rr":"4-2-2016" }, { "rr":"4-3-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-4-2016" }, { "rr":"4-5-2016" }, { "rr":"4-6-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-7-2016" }, { "rr":"4-8-2016" }, { "rr":"4-9-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-10-2016" }, { "rr":"4-11-2016" }, { "rr":"4-12-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-13-2016" }, { "rr":"4-14-2016" }, { "rr":"4-15-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-16-2016" }, { "rr":"4-17-2016" }, { "rr":"4-18-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-19-2016" }, { "rr":"4-20-2016" }, { "rr":"4-21-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-22-2016" }, { "rr":"4-23-2016" }, { "rr":"4-24-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-25-2016" }, { "rr":"4-26-2016" }, { "rr":"4-27-2016" },
    { "rr":"4-28-2016" }, { "rr":"4-29-2016" }, {"rr":"4-30-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-1-2016" },{ "rr":"5-2-2016" },{ "rr":"5-3-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-4-2016" },{ "rr":"5-5-2016"} ,{ "rr":"5-6-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-7-2016" },{ "rr":"5-8-2016" },{ "rr":"5-9-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-10-2016" },{ "rr":"5-11-2016" },{ "rr":"5-12-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-13-2016" },{ "rr":"5-14-2016" },{ "rr":"5-15-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-16-2016" },{ "rr":"5-17-2016" },{ "rr":"5-18-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-19-2016" },{ "rr":"5-20-2016" },{ "rr":"5-21-2016" },
    { "rr":"5-22-2016" },{ "rr":"5-23-2016" },{ "rr":"5-...16" },
    { "rr":"6-14-2016" },{ "rr":"6-15-2016" },{ "rr":"6-16-2016" },
    { "rr":"6-17-2016" },{ "rr":"6-18-2016" },{ "rr":"6-19-2016" },
    { "rr":"6-20-2016" },{ "rr":"6-21-2016" },{ "rr":"6-22-2016" },
    { "rr":"6-23-2016" },{ "rr":"6-24-2016" },{ "rr":"6-25-2016" },
    { "rr":"6-26-2016" },{ "rr":"6-27-2016" },{ "rr":"6-28-2016" },
    { "rr":"6-29-2016" },{ "rr":"6-30-2016" },{ "rr":"7-1-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-2-2016" },{ "rr":"7-3-2016" },{ "rr":"7-4-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-5-2016" },{ "rr":"7-6-2016" },{ "rr":"7-7-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-8-2016" },{ "rr":"7-9-2016" },{ "rr":"7-10-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-11-2016" },{ "rr":"7-12-2016" },{ "rr":"7-13-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-14-2016" },{ "rr":"7-15-2016" },{ "rr":"7-16-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-17-2016" },{ "rr":"7-18-2016" },{ "rr":"7-19-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-20-2016" },{ "rr":"7-21-2016" },{ "rr":"7-22-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-23-2016" },{ "rr":"7-24-2016" },{ "rr":"7-25-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-26-2016" },{ "rr":"7-27-2016" },{ "rr":"7-28-2016" },
    { "rr":"7-29-2016" },{ "rr":"7-30-2016" },{ "rr":"7-31-2016" },
    { "rr":"8-1-2016" },{ "rr":"8-2-2016" },{ "rr":"8-3-2016" },
    { "rr":"8-4-2016" },{ "rr":"8-5-2016" }
];
```

El cual convierto con moment js cada item; el resultado debe ser asi: abril-viernes-2016, abril-sabado-2016, abril-domingo-2016, etc ..... En navegadores como Chrome y en Android OS el resultado es correcto pero al mostrar el resultado en un alert en safari o IOS me da como resultado invalid date

```
for(var p = 0; p < nuevo.length; p++){
    alert(moment(nuevo[p].rr).format('MMMM-dddd-YYYY'));
}
```

Por que se da este error, que deberia hacer?

También tengo el siguiente error en consola:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
>   Arguments: [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que está ocurriendo aquí es que tus fechas no están en el formato de fechas estandard [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Moment.js usa internamente new Date() para crear las fechas y cuando le pasas un formato no estandar depende principalmente del navegador interpretar la fecha y por lo tanto en unos te funciona y en otros no.

La solución para esto es darle como formato de entradas a tus fechas el estandar aceptado que es algo como

```
 YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

Tu estas usando

```
M-D-YYYY
```

Almacena tus fechas en el formato estándard o transformalas manualmente antes de parsearlas. Te recomiendo siempre la primer variante.

Puedes leer un poco mas acerca del standard en el [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.9.1.1) de javascript y en los siguientes links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310953/invalid-date-in-safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: si es verdad y gracias lo pude solucionar